# Multiple filters in JSONPath

Tags: json, filter, jsonpath

I am trying to extract data using JSONPath, and using multiple filters.

In the JSON below, some have 'program.seriesId', and some don't. I want to extract the first 'value' that has no 'program.seriesId'

When I put the JSONPath below in the JSON evaluator http://jsonpath.com/:

```
$.data[?(@.program.seriesId)].value
```

I get 123 AND 345. However I only want the first 'value' of 123.

I've tried the following multiple filter JSONPaths, but all return no matches:

```
$.data[?(@.program.seriesId)][0].value
$.data[?(@.program.seriesId) && 0].value
$.data[?(@.program.seriesId) and 0].value
```

What is the JSONPath query to return the first 'value' , that has no 'program.seriesId'?

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "value": "123",
        "program": {
            "id": "011",
            "seriesId": "111"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": "234",
        "program": {
            "id": "022"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": "345",
        "program": {
            "id": "033",
            "seriesId": "333"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: did you find any sol ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonPath AND Operator on Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703891/jsonpath-and-operator-on-array)

Comment: "multiple filters" is misnomer here since you only have one filter: `?(@.program.seriesId)`. Please reword your question title/content.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for printing `1st result` object from the array of objects when I came across this question.

I found out that currently it is not possible to get index based result. [Github Open issue link](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272) , which is open since more than an year.

Otherwise it could have been something like this,

```
$.data[?(@.program.seriesId)][0].value
```