# How to do 2 filters if k8s' jsonpath is missing AND condition

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath

I need to find all sts whose replicas are still booting. For this I need to filter sts items based on 2 conditions:

- each item must have a `.status.readyReplicas` attribute
- each `readyReplicas` attribute must be different than the value in `replicas`

What I tried results in error:

```
$ kubectl get sts -o=jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.readyReplicas && @.status.readyReplicas!=@.status.replicas)]}{.}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.readyReplicas}{"/"}{.status.replicas}{"\n"}{end}'
error: error parsing jsonpath {range .items[?(@.status.readyReplicas && @.status.readyReplicas!=@.status.replicas)]}{.}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.readyReplicas}{"/"}{.status.replicas}{"\n"}{end}, unrecognized character in action: U+0026 '&'

$ kubectl get sts -o=jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.readyReplicas AND @.status.readyReplicas!=@.status.replicas)]}{.}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.readyReplicas}{"/"}{.status.replicas}{"\n"}{end}'
error: error executing jsonpath "{range .items[?(@.status.readyReplicas AND @.status.readyReplicas!=@.status.replicas)]}{.}{.metadata.name}{\"\\t\"}{.status.readyReplicas}{\"/\"}{.status.replicas}{\"\\n\"}{end}": Error executing template: unrecognized identifier AND. Printing more information for debugging the template: ...
```

The suggested solution on [JsonPath AND Operator on Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703891/jsonpath-and-operator-on-array) using comma doesn't work either:

```
$ k get sts -o=jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.readyReplicas), ?(@.status.readyReplicas!=@.status.replicas)]}{.}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.readyReplicas}{"/"}{.status.replicas}{"\n"}{end}'
error: error parsing jsonpath {range .items[?(@.status.readyReplicas), ?(@.status.readyReplicas!=@.status.replicas)]}{.}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.readyReplicas}{"/"}{.status.replicas}{"\n"}{end}, unclosed array expect ]
```

I'm looking for a k8s' jsonpath native solution, not workarounds with `jq`, etc. Thanks for helping.

Comment: For the time being, I'm using `kubectl rollout status ...` as a workaround.